# ObjectInputStream doesn´t get initialized

Tags: java, stream, serversocket, objectinputstream

I have a Problem with the ObjectInputStream. I wanna send Objects through this, but the program stops at the point where i want to initialize the ObjectInputStream. I already searched for answered and I found that the ObjectOutputstream needs to be open before you can initialize an ObjectInputStream. But this is defenitely done there.

Piece of code of my Client Class:

```
socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(server).getHostAddress(), 13340);
        messages = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        p = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        p.println("addServerContent");

        o.flush();
        System.out.println("1");
        o.writeObject(String.valueOf(index));
        o.writeObject(s);
```

And heres the part of the server:

```
}else if(what.equals("addServerContent")){
        ObjectInputStream i = null;
        try{
            i = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        }catch(IOException e){}

        while(GxMS2.ListUsed){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }

        try{

            System.out.println("1");
            int index = Integer.parseInt((String)i.readObject());
            ServerContent sc = (ServerContent)i.readObject();
```

At the server it doesn´t even reach the "1" mark.

Why isn´t it working?

Thank you

Comment: It either hangs here `while(GxMS2.ListUsed)` or somewhere else ...

Comment: No, its not there, i added a mark in front of the while and it didnt get triggered

Comment: "I found that the ObjectOutputstream needs to be open before you can initialize an ObjectInputStream" Absolutely not true

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551211/program-pauses-on-initializing-object-input-stream-in-java Answer 2, This is what I found, and it seems pretty logic

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine a character stream with an object stream so its either that you wrap the `OutputStream` with a `PrintWriter` or with an `ObjectOutputStream` but not both.

Comment: Why not? are they blocking each other?