# new ObjectInputStream blocks despite flushing OutputStream

Tags: java, networking, objectinputstream

At the moment i am trying to make some experiences with networking but i can't get past some point in the connection establishing process while using ObjectIn/OutputStreams.

I read in several Threads (like this one: [Java Creating a new ObjectInputStream Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658089/java-creating-a-new-objectinputstream-blocks) )on problems about the constructor of ObjectInputStream blocking and many suggest flushing the output first, so i came up with this:

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
String test = "test"; 
out.writeObject(test);
out.flush();
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
in = new ObjectInputStream(is);
```

The blocking line is the last one. 
Any suggestions why it is still failing to complete? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does the **other side** do? You're trying to read something, so the other side needs to write something. Since we have no idea of what the other side does, we can't help.

Comment: Oh, i see; i was misjudging what was happening under the surface when the server-socket accepts. Now things work even without the need to flush. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code you indicate will block until the peer has created an `ObjectOutputStream` on its socket, or written something else to the socket (which will cause a `StreamCorruptedException`).

Comment: I was misjudging who was the peer in the rest of the code due to my lacking understanding of the accept-method. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the `accept()` method. It has to do with the documented behaviour of object inputyand output streams.